# Cosa sono i "fitfit"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Noi Greco non avevamo soldi, a casa mia il contributo ai fuochi di fine anno era scarso. Mio padre comprava una scatola di **fitfit**, una di rotelle e una di esili razzi.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "fitfit" in questo brano. Immagino siano qualche tipo di fuochi d'artificio, ma potreste spiegarmi meglio in che cosa consistono?

Comment: Piccola correzione, se posso: le preposizioni che si accompagnano a "consistere" sono solo "in" e "di" (con significati diversi).  :)

Comment: Grazie mille, @Vincenzo, ho fatto la correzione.

Comment: Questi si chiamano "sparklers" in inglese.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A casa mia con il termine "fitfit" si indicano le stelline scintillanti, un tipo di fuochi d'artificio che emette scintille mentre brucia, sono dei bastoncini pirotecnici usati specialmente dai bambini perché meno pericolosi rispetto agli altri tipi di botte.

Non conosco il romanzo, ma su Google Books ho letto il passo menzionato (fonte: [Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=m9woCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT154&lpg=PT154&dq=stelline+o+fitfit+fuochi&source=bl&ots=qdYeD0no5M&sig=SHw-gN7AVRvENZTY4pTLM_jn5QI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi36OWF78XOAhUC7xQKHbjgBQAQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=stelline%20o%20fitfit%20fuochi&f=false)) e credo che il termine si riferisca alle stelline. Infatti, nel periodo citato la narratrice spiega che, essendo la sua famiglia povera, può permettersi solo pochi fuochi ed elenca tutti quelli che sono stati acquistati dal padre: fitfit, girandole e razzi.

Nel periodo seguente illustra che uso ne fanno, spiegando che lei mantiene le "stelline" o le girandole mentre il padre accende i razzi; i fitfit non sono più menzionati. Di conseguenza, secondo ciò che ha detto prima poichè non possono avere altri tipi di fuochi a disposizione credo che i "fitfit" corrispondano alle "stelline".

Qui c'è un'immagine delle stelline:
http://www.chimicare.org/curiosita/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/scatole-di-bastoncini-pirotecnici-300x199.jpg

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Sì, i fit fit si sparavano con una piccola rivoltella. Pasticchette in due strisce di carta velina rossa.

Comment: I fit fit nella mia infanzia a Napoli erano quello che dice Noemi, i bastoncini che facevano le stelline, questi: https://www.amazon.it/Zeus-Party-140-SCINTILLE-Scintillanti/dp/B0BHX196WG/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=stelline+scintillanti&qid=1694463302&sr=8-5.

Answer (score 2):

I "fitfit" o "fit fit" sono come immagini dei fuochi d'artificio; non so dirti come siano fatti con precisione ma dovrebbero essere dei piccoli petardi o miccette (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miccetta)

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Mai sentito, ma è plausibile. Ti andrebbe di fare qualche ricerca per corroborare la tesi?

Comment: Ho provato a fare qualche ricerca a supporto della mia memoria storica, credo che il nome derivi dall'omonima fabbrica cinese che li produce: http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/fitfitfireworks

Answer (score 0):

Ricordo bene cosa erano i fit fit: esisteva una pistolina per bambini così detta "a fit fit" e questa era formata da due striscette di carta larghe circa 1 centimetro, all'interno vi era posizionata della polvere pirica a mo' di piccola pastiglietta simile alla polvere dei fiammiferi, ma un po' più carica di polvere pirica. Il meccanismo della pistolina trascinava questa striscetta e sotto l'azione di un piccolo percussore che batteva su un pezzo di metallo piatto faceva esplodere il composto  emettendo un suono che non era proprio uno sparo ma più un suono tipo "fit fit". Era una pistolina che si regalava ai bambini che giocavano,  però innocua, ma che dava l'impressione "ai bambini" dello sparo.

Answer (score 0):

I "fitfit" erano formati da una striscia di cartone con tante goccie a forma di pastiglie che prima di essere usate venivano  tagliate singolarmente per poi essere sfegate come i cerini e una volta accesi scoppiettavano.